# transforming all data streamed to bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata, analytics

I need to change the format of each and every row which comes into bigquery from an external stream and since these rows are in a format which is nearly impossible to query, I should change the format and save it under a different dataset.

Since I am rather new to google cloud (I'm more proficient in aws echosystem) , I was wondering what is the best way to do it, from my understanding dataprep is incapable of changing an entire format , so I'm assuming I need to load it to spark or hadoop and then push the data back into big-query.

My use case is this

```
{"dimensions": {
        "date": "20180717",
        "name": "general",
        "params": [{
                "key": "value",
                "value": {
                    "string_value": null,
                    "int_value": "0",
                    "float_value": null,
                    "double_value": null
                }
            }, {
                "key": "somevent",
                "value": {
                    "string_value": "app12",
                    "int_value": null,
                    "float_value": null,
                    "double_value": null
                }
            }, {
                "key": "category",
                "value": {
                    "string_value": "regist",
                    "int_value": null,
                    "float_value": null,
                    "double_value": null
                }
            }, {
                "key": "act",
                "value": {
                    "string_value": "enter",
                    "int_value": null,
                    "float_value": null,
                    "double_value": null
                }
            }
        ],
        "timestamp_micros": "1531792452128000",
        "previous_timestamp_micros": "1531662845053000",
        "value_in_usd": null
    }
}
```

for instance, I would like to group by the counts of all key:category, meaning it would be simple for me, if the category value was actually a key and string_value would be at the top level.

thoughts?

Comment: could you please add sample of the schema/format you have, and number of records you have to help better offer a solution

Comment: most likely you just need to write right query that will do this transformation for you. I see you mentioned that "format ... is nearly impossible to query", but I would give it a try. so give us an example of initial schema and desired schema as well as some data examples

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant , 
ty, added a json export

Comment: the example you showed - please clarify - is this stored as a string in one column? or it represents schema with repeated records and so on?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant  yes, unfortunately, it is saved as a repeated record

Comment: so, you should show the schema. and btw, why you think it is unfortunate - i think it is a quite powerful feature here. anyway  - provide more details  - and soon you will see how easy it most likely will be for you and you see the power of BigQuery

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks. 
What I would like to know if there is a way to make a key out of a value and have another field value as the value of that key. 

for instance in my example,  it would be easier if  regist was a value of a key and the schema had  "category" as a field. 

regarding the entire schema, I need to check if I can reveal it here.

Comment: Sorry, @roeezi, if you have regist as key and category as field, which ones would be the category fields? category: int_value/float_value/double_value?? I guess you couldn't reveal the entire desired schema, if you are still interested, my you share an simplified example one or something like this in order to understand the changes that you want to perform?